# Displaying Tables at the bottom of the Table Layout in android

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to display the Table rows that starts from the middle of the Layoutpage. When i did the code the table rows are always showing at the top,

i have tried to implement table layout with in Relative layout.This did not worked. 
I have changed the layout_height="200dp" option. This didn't worked either.

How can i solve this?

The code that i tried is below

```
<TableLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"        
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:showDividers="middle"   
android:shrinkColumns="*"  
android:stretchColumns="*" 
android:background="#ffffff">

<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"> 

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sunsign"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/sunsign"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/sunsign"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:background="#17543F"/>

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/services"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/services"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:src="@drawable/services"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:background="#17543F"/> 

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/sermons"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:src="@drawable/sermons" 
    android:contentDescription="@string/sermons"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:background="#17543F"/>
```

Comment: Can you put a picture up explaining what you want?  Or try to clarify this?  I'm unsure what you want  vs what is happening.

Comment: Your tablelayout is your main layout, you cant "move" it to the middle, unless you implement 2 linearLayouts the first stand the 1st half of the screen, the second one with the tablelayout inside (for example!)

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner -can you please look the picture from this url (https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bze-JWq18hkVRTUyWmFuM2dDb0E/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />
    <TableLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout_weight value allows you to fill percentages of the screen.  The text view is a placeholder here - you can put whatever you want there.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your TableRow's gravity to "bottom".

```
<TableRow 
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom" >
...
```